# Windows PhotoAppplication loads very slowly

Tags: windows-photo-viewer

My Windows PHOTO application takes forever to load and closes unexpectedly.

Is there any other easier fix and deleting and reinstalling?

Answer (score 0):

Some possible solutions:

1. **Run Windows Store Apps Troubleshooter**
   Run Windows
   *Settings > Update & Security > Troubleshoot > Windows Store Apps*
   and follow on-screen directions.
2. **Reset Photos App**
   Windows *Settings > Apps > Apps & features*, scroll to and click "Microsoft Photos",
   click *Advanced Options > Reset*. You might try *Repair* first.
3. **Check for update**
   Go to *Microsoft Store > 3-dots > Downloads and Updates > Installed*,
   click "Microsoft Photos", and check if there is any update for it.
4. **Re-install**
   If Reset of Photos doesn't work, then use Powershell to reinstall the app.
   Run "Windows Powershell" as Administrator and enter the commands:

   ```
   get-appxpackage Microsoft.Windows.Photos | remove-appxpackage
   Get-AppxPackage -allusers Microsoft.Windows.Photos | Foreach {Add-AppxPackage -DisableDevelopmentMode -Register "$($_.InstallLocation)\AppXManifest.xml"
   ```
5. If all fails,
   [get the old Windows Photo Viewer working in Windows 10 with Winaero Tweaker](https://winaero.com/blog/how-get-windows-photo-viewer-working-in-windows-10/),
   or use another paint application such as
   [paint.net](https://www.getpaint.net/).